# Compare Magento Go and X-Cart by specific requirements. What is more suitable?

Tags: comparison

company where I'm work decided to change current online store and use existing eCommerce solutions. We are looking on 3 options: **Magento Go**, **X-Cart** or build it **by ourselves**. The problem is that some functionality and further extensions are quite unique and we not sure that existing eCommerce can handle it. Magento Enterprise cost $15,550/year and it's what we can not offer, so option only is Go version.

As no one in our company ever work with Magento or X-Cart, we can not make right decision based on our knowledge. I'm asking your expert opinion about what we can or can't do in Magento Go or X-Cart. Please answer if you really have good experience with one or both of that systems.

Here are some requirements:

- Users must be pre-authorized before enter the site (like CMS, asking login and password)
- Users should have their profile page with info about purchased items
- Integration with external DB where we store our products and prices (grab data from external source)
- Stock availability and tracking (update shipping info)
- Support multy user categories with different prices for each group
- Users should be linked with country and see prices for their country (I think that it's part of DB integration)
- Products may be combined in a group when purchase selected amount and apply discount
- Make sales for specific user category
- SKU must be generated by specific rules (for example: Shirt-S-Yellow, Shirt-M-Green)
- Keep order opened for a day even after you logged out and then send order to proceed
- Customized pages
- Support Credit Cards (looks like it's supported by both systems)
- SSL (the same, looks like supported)
- Easy to manage from back-end

If something is impossible to do, then probably we have to build that system by ourselves.
Maybe some of requirements are sound stupid, but as I said, we don't have any experience with Magento and X-Cart. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping for a platform. My suggestion is to take the time to review each platform in a demo/test environment and ask specific questions vs dumping a list of requirements here for us to validate.

Comment: Thanks @davidalger The reason why I'm asking it here is because we have to spend too much time to investigate if all that requirement are possible or not. To find an answer we need to implement some features and see if it's working or not, but we don't have that time. Maybe someone had similar issues and can just say: "Yes, you can do it" or "No, there are platform limitations". I don't need a solution, just personal experience with similar problems.

Comment: I understand it takes time to do research. It'll take more time to implement regardless of platform. Both are open source platforms though. I.e. Magento Community Edition and X-Cart are, Magento Go is pretty much take it or leave it, but has a free trial. In reality, you can customize them any way you want and it will work. It's more a matter how much functionality you have to build vs built-in functionality you can use unmodified and how long it takes while taking the learning curve into account.

Comment: Thanks @davidalger probably it's what I want to hear. If it's fully customizable and don't really have limitations for extensions, then it's good for us. I really thought that there are some limits in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this, since I went through these sorts of questions 6 months ago.

I am also writing from experience with Magento Community Edition, and I don't how much it will differ from Magento Go.

**Pre-Authorize Users:** Nothing like this built-in, but you might be able to find an extension or write something that does this. Check [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) for this and other extensions you might need.

Without extensions, you could hide all of your products to customers who are not logged in. Then you could move all registered users to a specific group that has access to all (or some) products.

**Profile Pages:** Built in.

**Integration with external DB:** Not really possible. Magento has a pretty intricate database spanning nearly 400 Tables. There are a number of tools out there though that will help with importing products into Magento.

**Stock Management:** Built in

**User Groups:** Built in

**International Pricing:** I don't have much experience with this, but I believe some functionality with this is built in, and is managed by different store views, I believe (A magento installation can handle many stores and websites within it, and share settings between them)

**Generated SKUs:** Best solution is a [Configurable Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) in Magento, but you'll have to build the SKUs yourself.

**Keep order opened for a day even after you logged out and then send order to proceed:** Need more information here

**Customized Pages:** Yup

**Easy to Manage Backend:** Magento Backend is pretty straightforward

Comment: thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. The most important was Pre-Authorized users and external DB integration. I really appreciate your answer.